# Creating a Photo Album in expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to create a photo album app in MEVN.

The **req.body.ALBUM** will become the folder's name then for the req.body.DESCRIPTION is just its description.

What my code accomplished was just it can create the folder but it creates an undefined folder then save the images inside it.

**NOTE:** I tried to create an empty folder and change the directory to my sample folder and it can successfully save the images there.

Here is my full code that can only create the folder but not saves the images inside it rather it saves the image in the undefined folder.

```
router.post('/album', (req, res) => {
    let sql = "INSERT INTO GALLERY SET ALBUM = ?, DESCRIPTION = ?";
    let body = [req.body.ALBUM, req.body.DESCRIPTION]
    myDB.query(sql, body, (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            let directory = `C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\project\\myproject\\public\\${req.body.ALBUM}`;
            fse.mkdirp(directory, err => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log("Success");
                }
            });
            const myStorage = multer.diskStorage({
                destination: directory,
                filename: function (req, file, cb) {
                    cb(null, file.originalname + path.extname(file.originalname))
                }
            });
            const myUploads = multer({
                storage: myStorage, limits: {
                    //10 Million
                    fileSize: 10e6
                }
            }).array('files', 15);


            if (fse.exists(directory)) {
                myUploads(req, res, (error) => {
                    if (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    } else {
                        res.send("Success")
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                console.log(false);
            }

        }
    })
})
```

When it comes to this part, the **req.body.ALBUM** becomes undefined therefore the images were saved inside undefined folder.

```
const myStorage = multer.diskStorage({
            destination: directory,
            filename: function (req, file, cb) {
                cb(null, file.originalname + path.extname(file.originalname))
            }
        });
```

Comment: fse.mkdirp(directory, err => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    //upload image here
                    console.log("Success");
                }
    });

wait for directory to be created and then upload images. Right now both operations are in parellel

Comment: what do you mean parallel? sorry it's new to me the word parallel when it comes to programming

Comment: In javascript I/O is handled using event loop. in your code when you do 

> fse.mkdirp(directory, err => {
>                 if (err) {
>                     console.log(err);
>                 } else {
>                     console.log("Success");
>                 } });

this code is asynchronous which means even though this operation is not completed it will move to next line of code and executes it.
That is why in next line
   
`directory` is undefined

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
fse.mkdirp(directory, err => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {


             const myStorage = multer.diskStorage({
                 destination: directory,
                 filename: function (req, file, cb) {
                   cb(null, file.originalname + path.extname(file.originalname))
                }
             });
            }
});
```

Here you are waiting for first operation to complete